# PowerShell Timelapse variable to be used to identify files based on 'lastwritetime'

Tags: powershell, datetime, scripting

I have a scheduled task that runs shortly after I login. The scheduled task does some magic on reports stored on a remote server and copies files back to me if there is a match. I do not log in every day for my scheduled task to execute consistently on a daily basis every day of the week so I'm looking for a current solution that can ensure on the day I do log back in, the script will identify the time lapse in terms of hours, then search for reports created over weekends and such based on 'last write time' and run on those reports that were missed.

My initial thoughts were to identify the time lapse since the last time my scheduled task ran:

`$timelapseinhours = ((Get-Date) - (Get-ScheduledTask -taskname reportmagic | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select-Object Lastruntime).Lastruntime).TotalHours`

Then I would add this to my scheduled task script in such a way so days that I am off, reports are calculated and found based on lastwritetime when the scheduled task runs again when I log in:

`Get-ChildItem - Path $sourcepath -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name - match $filenamingconvention -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le $timelapseinhours)} | Copy-Item -Container -Destination $destinationpath -Recurse`

However, instead of calculating the difference and doing what I need, I get the following error:

`Could not compare "05/01/2020 11:33:30" to "1.91101793". Error: "Cannot convert value "1.91101793" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""`

`05/01/2020 11:33:30` is the Lastwritetime of one of the files.

`1.91101793` is the timelapse in hours from last time the scheduled task ran.

Could someone please help me with writing up a working script to identify the last time my scheduled task script was run and find files created over the time frame of my absence between last scheduled task run and current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a LHS `[datetime]` instance to a `[double]` RHS (your `$timelapseinhours` value), which is what the error implies.

I suggest *not* calculating a time span in hours, and to simply compare `[datetime]` instances:

```
$lastRunTime = (
  Get-ScheduledTask -taskname reportmagic | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
).LastRunTime

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourcepath -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { 
   $_.Name -match $filenamingconvention -and $_.LastWriteTime -ge $lastRunTime 
  } | 
   Copy-Item -Container -Destination $destinationpath -Recurse
```

Note the use of `-ge` rather than `-le` so as to find the files created *after* `$lastRunTime`.